# IOS Notification of other app's voip call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, voip

I'm trying to track voip calls made on the device. Is there anyway to register for a notification when a voip call is started and then ended. Basically, I just want my app to be able to receive the event that the voip app does when the socket has activity on it, or at least ANY event that will at least let me know that the call has happened.

Is there a framework for this? (I know of coretelephony for regular mobile service calls) Or is there a "hacky" way to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. iPhone is heavily locked down.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't come off as sarcastic or too simple, but couldn't you just log [NSDate date] at the beginning and end of the call in code and use NSTimeInterval to see how long it is?

Comment: Well, I can do that when the notification comes through, however the problem is actually being notified when a voip call event happens. Currently I track mobile calls the way you suggested, but I'm really looking for a way to be notified that a voip call has happened, I'll update the question title